# App for android

Tags: android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!!! I'd like to do an app to my android device than publish in a topic in my notebook. How can I do this? Is there any tutorial to beginners?? Thank you!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28109/app-for-android/) by [arubu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1832/arubu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a good overview of the Applications Platform here: [Applications Platform Overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/ApplicationsPlatformOverview)

You can check out the documentation here as well: [Applications Platform Links](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform)

If you're developing on Linux there's a good description of how to set up your environment here: [Clients/Android](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android)

And there's a step-by-step tutorial for how to write the simple Pr2 Props App here: [How to Write Pr2 Props](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android/Tutorials/HowToWritePr2Props)

If you just want to publish messages to a topic on your computer then a good app to use as a template would be the Teleop app. It publishes messages directly to topics. If you've set up your environment as described on the wiki then you can roscd to android_teleop to take a look at that code.

If you have any trouble finding anything or if there's anything missing from the documentation, please let me know.

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [selliott](https://answers.ros.org/users/1745/selliott/) with karma: 51 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0